# JavaScript/MIDI API to manipulate MIDI files

Tags: javascript, python, midi

I need to write a utility program to manipulate MIDI type 0/1 files. 
The API can work online or offline and should be open source.
I really prefer to write it in JavaScript ( it is OK if it has cross-browser compatibility issues). The API must be capable of

- reading Markers in the MIDI tracks and also
- course distinguishing events from different channels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should it be able to work offline? Do you want a JavaScript library or an online service? What is your budget?

Comment: It does not matter, online or offline. The cheapest.

Comment: Please add this information into the question, the comments will be deleted. Thanks! :-)